# Layout screen shot with gridview

Tags: android, gridview, textview, screenshot

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/screenshotlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="320dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:background="@color/DarkGrey"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="TextView LinearLayout"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >

            <requestFocus />
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my layout. Where Gridview works like vertical scroll bar. I m adding bitmaps dynamically to that Gridview. Gridvies size may vary.

Answer (score 0):

This how you can get a Bitmap screenshot of your layout:

1. Add an ID to your layout (mine is called "screen"):

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>    android:id="@+id/screen"
>    android:layout_width="match_parent"
>    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>    <!--//add your buttons, texts, other layouts, etc here-->
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

1. This is how you can capture the screen shot programatically:

> View screen = screen = (View) findViewById(R.id.screen);
>      View rootview = screen.getRootView();
>      rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
>
> Bitmap bitmap = rootview.getDrawingCache();

This worked for me. You can use the method .setImageBitmap(bitmap)  on an ImageView to display the screen shot.

Comment: Hi Harith thanks for your reply :-). As i mentioned i can take the screen shot of layout or a scroll view and gridview. Here in my application i want to take screen shot of gridview with textview which is below of gridview. Gridview works like vertical scrollview. I cannot put textview inside Gridview ad gridview is a widget.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if your GridView and TextView are inside a LinearLayout, you can add an ID to the LinearLayout and then take a screen shot of both GridView and TextView using the LinearLayout's ID.

Comment: The height of the linear layout is constant. if i take the screen shot of the linear layout the it gives the screen shot which is appearing on the screen, but the gridvew contains more than the eight of the screen. Gridview is working as vertcal scroll bar inside the linear layout.